# Recurrence relation for T(n) of Top-Down approach solution of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, math, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

1. What is the recurrence for T(n) of this code and the initial conditions of this recurrence? Notice that the code is in python and it is a top-down procedure solution for the Fibonacci sequence 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21... where

T(3) = 5 <-- number of calls of Fibonacci (3)

T(4) = 7

T(5) = 9

T(6) = 11

T(7) = 13

T(8) = 15

T(9) = 17

T(10) = 19

```
//**The code is:**

"""
1. The first Fib method calls itself recursively applies the top-down procedure.
"""
totalCalls = 0

def FibHelper(n, memo):
   global totalCalls
   totalCalls+=1 
   if memo[n] == -1:
       if n < 2: 
           memo[n] = n
       else:
           left = FibHelper(n-1, memo)
           right = FibHelper(n-2, memo)
           memo[n] = left + right
   return memo[n]

"""
This method sets up the array first and then calls the FibHelper() method.
"""
def Fib(n):
   global totalCalls
   totalCalls = 0
   print("The fibonacci number of (%d) is: %d" % (n, FibHelper(n, [-1] * (n+1))))
   print("The total number of calls in TD is: ",totalCalls)
```

2. Use Fib(n) above to empirically verify that T(n)=2F(n+1)-1 is correct.

I need a solution for Fibonacci sequence **with** top-down procedure.
This qustion is to find a recuarance relation of the code above.

So, what I need is something like T(n) = F(....) or T(n-1)...
For example, the recurance relation for the Fibonacci sequence **without** top-down procedure is
T(n)=2F(n+1)-1 which shows the number of function F(n) calls where F(n) code is:

```
"""
This is an orginal Fib
"""
totalCalls = 0

def F(n):
    global totalCalls
    totalCalls+=1    
    if n <= 1: 
        return n
    else:
        return F(n-1) + F(n-2)

def FStart(n):
    global totalCalls
    totalCalls = 0
    print("The fibonacci number of (%d) is: %d" % (n, F(n)))
    print("The total number of calls is: ",totalCalls)
```

where,
T(0) = 1 call for the function to find Fibonacci of 0

T(5) = 15 calls for the function to find Fibonacci of 15

T(8) = 67

T(10) = 177

you can apply the 2F(n+1)-1 or the code of F(n) to get the same result for those lines.

Answer (score 1):

> This question is to find a recurrence relation of the code above.

The base case is when  is 0 or 1. In those cases `totalCalls` increments once. So:

<sub>0</sub> = 1
      <sub>1</sub> = 1

For a greater value of , there is the initial increment of `totalCalls` and a recursive call `left = FibHelper(n-1, memo)`. That recursive call gets the same `memo` state, and so we can apply a recurrence relation here:  is 1+<sub>─1</sub> by the time that recursive call returns. The second recursive call `right = FibHelper(n-2, memo)` will find that `memo` has the needed value, and therefore `totalCalls` will only increase once more. This gives us:

= 1 + <sub>─1</sub> + 1 = <sub>─1</sub> + 2

In summary, the recurrence relation is given by:

<sub>0</sub> = 1
      <sub>1</sub> = 1
       = <sub>─1</sub> + 2, for  > 1

It can be solved to a non-recursive relation:

= max(1, 2─1)

Comment: what about this part: Use Fib(n) above to empirically verify that T(n)=2F(n+1)-1 is correct.

Comment: That is part of an assignment. Your question was to "find a recurrence relation of the code above". If you have a second question, then please ask a new question. On Stack Overflow questions should be one question at a time. If you decide to post a new question, then make sure to add your attempt to "empirically verify", as currently there is no trace of that in your post. But I will be happy to look at your next question if you post one.